# Maya UI not docking after rerunning script

Tags: python, pyqt, maya

I have made a UI window for Autodesk Maya 2015. Every time I run the script within Maya's script editor, it works fine, the UI gets launched and it docks properly on the main Maya window.

However, after closing the UI window and rerunning the script, the window doesn't dock anymore. It gets stuck on the main screen and I have to close the whole software. It seems that the UI can't find the main Maya Window anymore after I close it the first time round. I'm not sure how to fix this. Can anyone give me some advice on how to fix this problem?

Here is my code:

```
def getMayaWindow():
    ptr = apiUI.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
    if ptr is not None:
        return shiboken.wrapInstance(long(ptr), QtGui.QMainWindow)

class pipeWindow(formClass,baseClass):
    def __init__(self, parent=getMayaWindow()):
        super(pipeWindow,self).__init__(parent) 

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setObjectName('pipe_window')

        try:
            cmds.deleteUI('dockPane')
        except:
            pass                
        self.pane = cmds.paneLayout('dockPane', cn='single')

        if 'pipeDock' not in cmds.lsUI(ctl=1) :
            cmds.dockControl('pipeDock', con=self.pane, area='right', 
                              allowedArea = ['right','left'], label = 
                             "ANMD_Pipeline", w=365)            
        else:
            pass
        cmds.control( 'pipe_window', e=True, p=self.pane)
```

Comment: It'd be useful to see formClass and baseClass implementations (I assume they're PySide UIs, right?). Multiple inheritance can be tricky (if you're not familiar with it, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/3277407/8200213). Also, the whole `pipeWindow` structure is unclear to me: you parent some PySide UI (likely just `formClass`) to the main window but then you pass a `paneLayout` to `dockControl`: I don't get how can it work, even on first excecution. If you're not precious about your current solution, consider using `MayaQWidgetDockableMixin`; otherwise please explain the code further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying out multiple things, I have managed to resolve this issue. I have used

```
if cmds.dockControl('pipeDock', q=1, ex=1):
    cmds.deleteUI('pipeDock')
```

Then I have a `super(className, self).closeEvent(event)` inside a `closeEvent` function. This did the trick for me. This did the trick for me. Previously I had the `cmds.deleteUI` within my `closeEvent` function which did not work, I suspect it was because I did not close the Event itself, so the UI just hides  itself whenever I press the cross button instead of deleting it.